# pause N goroutines inside handlerFunc

Tags: go, caching, mutex, blocking, goroutine

currently im implementing a caching system using std lib http/net.

An endpoint parses a key and validates the request using the `isOK(key)` function. If it is not okay, one routine is send to `makeSureNowOK(key,edpoint)` to make sure, `isOk(key)` will return `true` at the next request.

My simplified solution looks as follows:

```
func (ep *Endpoint) Handler() func(...) {
        for {           
            ep.mu.Lock()
            // WAITINGROOM //
            //lint:ignore SA2001 empty critical section
            ep.mu.Unlock()
            bytesBody, err := isOK(key)
            if err != nil {
                select {
                case <-ep.pause:
                    go makeSureNowOK(key)
                default:
                }
            } else {
                ...
                return
            }
        }
}


func makeSureNowOK(key string, ep ...) {

    ep.mu.Lock()
    
    ... do validation ..    
    ep.pause <- struct{}{}
    ep.mu.Unlock()

}
```

So I'm using a mutex to block further executions and a channel using select to catch back routines that passed the isOK function.

Another Idea to not use mutex is to use a closed channel to allow routines to pass. But then I have to recreate it, to block routines. That feels somewhat hacky.

How would you approach this problem?

Edit: To make my question more clear: The code above is working like so. But I feel like creating a "Waitingroom" by calling `.Unlock()` immediately after `.Lock()` is not a clean way to achieve this. Do you have other suggestions?

An alternative way would be to use sync waitgroup, but then I'd have to call `waitgroup.Wait` (where right now im un/locking the mutex which will be before `waitgroup.Add` which is aswell bad.

Comment: can you state the problem you're trying to solve? Without mentioning the functions calls, I don't really know what `isOk` is supposed to represent

Comment: My point is use sync.map

Comment: isOk is a redid get request. The code is working like this. To state the problem: I am not sure if the usage of mutex is the right way to go here. Even the linter says: Don't immediately lock and unlock just to create a "Waitingroom"

Comment: A lock/unlock doesn't give you any assurances, it has no value. It's not clear what your intended behavior is here, but the linter is right, there's something wrong here.

Comment: Basically I want all other goroutines, that are started  the handler function, to block, if isOK returns an error. then, just one new goroutine should be started to fix that error. The intended behavior of the mutex is to block other routines, before calling isOK, that will return an error (because the error is currently fixed by another goroutine, and will return error for sure)